# Viber бот: каким должен быть ответ?

Tags: php, бот, viber

Пишу бота для Viber на php. Когда приходить хук, делаю ответ с кодом 200 и сообщением

```
{"status": "0"}
```

Но он продолжает отправлять запросы. Такое ощущение, что он не видит правильного ответа. Может он ждет не такого ответа?

И как можно посмотреть, есть ли не успешные запросы и очистить их?

Comment: Писал интеграцию с вайбер. У меня сервер просто 'ok' возвращает и всё работает